# If condition not working in server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If condition to equal two string values in javascript is not working in server, but its working in localhost. Given below is my code.

```
var res_id = $(this).attr('name');
        var fld_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ans    = $('#'+fld_id).attr('value');
        //var mod_id = $('#mod_id').attr('value');
        //alert(typeof(ans));
        $.post("multiple_check_answer.php", { resid: res_id, answ: ans}, function(data){

            //alert(typeof data);
            if(ans==data)
            {
                //alert(data);
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+ans).css({'color':'green', 'font-weight':'bold'});

            }
            else
            {
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+ans).css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+data).css({'color':'green', 'font-weight':'bold'});

            }


        });
```

for ex. if `ans` and `data` values are `A` but its showing red color.

Comment: What does `data` return?

Comment: string value `A`

Comment: Have you tried `if(ans===data)`?

Comment: And `ans` when you do a `console.log(ans);` inside the `post`?

Comment: @daniel yes I tried that also.

Comment: @Ionut its console showing `A`

Comment: And the type of the variable `ans`...? Also you should note that you can't have same ids.

Comment: @Ionut type of `ans` is string.

Comment: Ok. Then it should work. There is maybe another problem in your code. Please make a http://jsfiddle.net that demostrates your exact problem.

Comment: @Ionut please check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/g9hknaxn/1/

Comment: The link in the post request is dead. Without the `AJAX` request the code seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/g9hknaxn/2/

Comment: @Ionut thats correct, but I think the `data` value return from the url is the issue. So i changed that to return integer value if true `1` else  `0`. Now it seems to be working fine. thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You said `data` returns `string value A` when I asked. That was the first question I asked. Anyway, I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new code which is working fine. Changed data value to integer.

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        var res_id = $(this).attr('name');
        var fld_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ans    = $('#'+fld_id).attr('value');
        //var mod_id = $('#mod_id').attr('value');
        //alert(ans);
        $.post("multiple_check_answer.php", { resid: res_id, answ: ans}, function(data){

            //alert(data);
            if(data==1)
            {
                //alert(data);
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+ans).css({'color':'green', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                //$('#dis_msg'+res_id).html('<strong style="color:green">Your Answer is Correct</strong>');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+ans).css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                $('#span_'+res_id+'_'+data).css({'color':'green', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                //$('#dis_msg'+res_id).html('<strong style="color:red">Your Answer is In-Correct</strong>');
            }



        });

    });
```